# "check out" vs. "look at"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, sense-verbs

Consider the following:

> **Check (out)** the portfolio and let me know if you are interested via e-mail.

or

> **Look at** the portfolio and let me know if you are interested via e-mail.

Can I use *check*, *check out* or *look at*?

I need it to be as simple as possible, so *take a look* is not an option for me right now.

My guess is that *look at* is the most formal one, so should I use it when talking to a client or is *check* OK, too?

Comment: What is the intricacy in the use of **take a look**?

Comment: Too many words ;) I have a limited space, to make a long story short.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Check*, at least in British English, carries with it the suggestion that the reader should scrutinize the portfolio for errors. *Look at* is more general. *Take a look at* is less formal, and could be used in many contexts. Whatever verb you use, your message might have a more favourable reception if you soften the peremptory tone that a direct imperative conveys. You might therefore like to consider these alternatives, or variations of them, depending on the nature of your relationship with the client:

*I should be grateful if you would examine the portfolio . . .*

*You might like to look through the portfiolio . . .*

*You might find it helpful to look through the portfiolio . . .*

Comment: Your alternatives are perfect!

Comment: Thanks, so I will stick with Look at because of the lack of "space" in my application. But also the other suggestions will be really useful in a conversation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

"Check out" is a better alternative, as it means "to appraise". "Look at" is definitely not wrong, but seems (to me) to be asking for a more superficial answer, which is made just by looking, rather than observing in detail, as "check out" implies.